# Question migration was mistaken

Tags: support, migration

I had my question migrated from the site where a couple of similar (not the same) and appropriate tags were available to the site where (I think by my little experience) nobody specializes on topic and no tags available.

More than that, I tried to post it after all where it supposed to be and now I have this post locked.

Some questions:

- Can I cancel a mistaken migration?
- Does it mean I can't expect any answer at all for sure now?
- Or it is something I can do?

Comment: In future you should ask questions about specific posts or site-specific issues on that sites meta.

Comment: I assume it was [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/global-blue-with-d-visa-netherlands-possible); Expatriates rejected the migration, so it's back on Travel, its original spot. Now you just need to edit the question so it's on-topic, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can flag your own question on the site where it was migrated to, choose "Other" and explain why the migration was wrong. Moderator on that site can migrate it back to the previous site, and leave "official" comment there to prevent it from being migrated again.

You also better ask this on the per-site meta of the original site.